# RED5 and IOS - Streaming using MediaLib and CommLib, stream makes unusual noise

Tags: ios, xcode, red5

I downloaded MediaLib demos from Github and tried video and audio streaming using RED5 media Server. I ran the RED5 Server and started the RTMPStreamComeBack client App in Xcode and i could successfully steam live. But when streaming, the audio makes an usual noise every 2 seconds or so and audio just glitches.

Here i the code for the client in IOS: I just modified the RTMP URL and stream name, just hard coded these values,

I do get some errors in the RED5 Console when the steam is coming back, but can't seem to make out what these errors are.

http://pastebin.com/0KQvTL0b

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MediaLib, chould you share the link? Also I may not be able to assist being that this is iOS based.

Comment: @Mondain, hi thanks for getting back to me, i have opened another question if you would look at it please. Its kind of what progress i have made and where its going wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026472/wowza-to-ios-how-to-live-stream